# Не корректно выполняется метод в CefSharp (WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded)

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Всем привет. Пытаюсь  сделать  следующее:

1. Переходим по ссылке
2. Страница открывается в  новой вкладке
3. Ждем загрузки страницы
4. После загрузки  страницы- выполнить скрипт
5. Закрываем  вкладку.

Код ниже самого метода:

В методе инициализации:

WBBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += WBBrowserFrameLoadEnded;

```
private void WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        WebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelectorAll('#table > ul > li > div > ui > span').click()" + ";");
    }
}
```

В какой-то  момент, а именно  когда  возвращаешься  на  первоначальную страницу- просто закрывается приложение. Если убрать выполнение скрипта- приложение работает 100% стабильно. Что делаю не так??? Как можно поправить??? СПАСИБО

Comment: Приложение закрывается с каким-то исключением? Вы пробовали try-catch использовать в этом методе?

Comment: Может работать и все будет ок,  а  потом раз зависла  и закрылась без и исключения. Try и catch не пробовал  использовать